# Javascript: Maintaining position of elements in parent div when rescaled

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drag

I'm trying to save an elements position after it has been dragged and dropped (using Top and Left) and then place it correctly when it is reloaded (even if the parent container has a different size).

Right now what Im doing is that I let the user move the element around in the parent (#diagram-editor-canvas), then upon Save I convert the top and left pixel values to percentages using:

```
  var w = $("#diagram-editor-canvas").width();
  var h = $("#diagram-editor-canvas").height();
  var Xpercent = parseInt(span.style.left.split('p')[0]) / w * 100;
  var Ypercent = parseInt(span.style.top.split('p')[0])  / h * 100;
```

span being my dragged element. My thinking being that if the parent container size changes the use of percentage should make sure the element is always in the right place. Sadly, this doesnt seem to work? My elements seem to be randomly misplaced upon reloading the page and positioning the element with the saved percentage. Am I missing something? Is there and offset I'm supposed to take into account?

My span draggable element looks something like this (the top and left values changing on drag):

```
top: 251px;
left: 348px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 1000;
transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
-webkit-user-select: none;
touch-action: none;
cursor: move;
```

While my parent container has these properties:

```
margin: 20px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-image: url(/uploads/schematics/3.png);
background-size: contain;
position: relative;
```

Any ideas? Im at a loss

Answer (score 0):

I was being silly, I forgot to calculate the new aspect-ratio height for the container both when calculating the percentage on save and when previewing it on a different size.